# Como obtener el valor de varios td al seleccionar un checkbox con Javascrip

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, tablas, alert

soy nuevo programando y mi pregunta es la siguiente, Tengo una tabla HTML que se llena en automático de acuerdo a los registros de la Base, quisiera que al seleccionar cualquier checkbox, me arrojara una alerta mostrando Id, nombre y Ap_Materno, de la fila correspondiente. Hice una prueba asignando al id y value del checkbox, los valores de la tabla, pero solo me arroja el id y nombre, mas no el apellido, esto quisiera hacerlo con Javascrip

Mi tabla

```
<?php
//Se incluye la conexion
    include_once 'conexion.php';

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM registros";
    $stmt = $conexion->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();
    $resultado = $stmt-> get_result();
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="estilo.css">

    <title>Listado de Personas</title>
</head>

<body>
    <br><br>
        <div class="contenedor">
        <h1> Listado de Usuarios </h1>
            <table id="tabla">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Selecciona</th>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nombres</th>
                        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
                        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                    <tbody >
                        <?php foreach ($resultado as $fila){ ?>
                            
                            <!--  Se muestra el valor de cada columna en la tabla,  Asigno al check en id y value los valores que deseo obtener en la alerta -->
                            <tr>
                                <td><input type="checkbox" id="<?php echo $fila ['id']; ?>" name="checkname" value="<?php echo $fila ['nombre']; ?>" class="classchk"></td>
                                <td id="id"><?php echo $fila ['id']; ?></td>
                                <td id="nombre"><?php echo $fila ['nombre']; ?></td>
                                <td id="ap_pat"><?php echo $fila ['ap_paterno']; ?></td>
                                <td id="ap_mat"><?php echo $fila ['ap_materno']; ?></td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php }; ?> 
                           
                    </tbody>
                    </table>
        </div>
</body>
<script src="alerta.js"></script>
</html>

Mi Funcion en JS

var tabla=document.getElementById("tabla"); 
tabla.addEventListener('change', function(e){ 
  e.preventDefault(); /
    var checkboxes = document.getElementsByName('checkname'); 
      for(var i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++){ 
        if(checkboxes[i].checked==true){ 
          alert("El id seleccionado es: "+checkboxes[i].id+" y nombre es: "+checkboxes[i].value); 
        }
      }    
});
```

Comment: los `td` no tienen valores; tienen texto entre sus etiquetas de apertura y cierre.

Comment: no has indicado que resultado tiene el javascript; algun error o no es lo esperado? tienes que agregar mas datos ya que tu codigo no se puede reproducir.

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 el resultado del TD es el valor que tiene cada campo en la DB

Comment: @ArcanisGK507 el resultado que muestra el JS es el ID y el Nombre, esto seleccionando cada Chek, pero requiero que me muestre Id, nombre y ap_paterno al seleccionar un check

Comment: ok entonces tiene un mal concepto; primero que nada la tabla no tiene evento de cambio ... quien cambia es el checkbox...

Comment: tienes que navegar en el DOM a partir de que sabes cual es el TD padre del checkbox en donde ocurre el evento; entonces buscas los TD Hermanos y el texto que contienen...

Comment: asi es, el que cambia es el checkbox

Comment: no te lo pregunte ... te lo dije por que en evento onChange esta mal asignado

Answer (score 0):

Primeramente, no tiene sentido agregar una escucha de eventos global sobre la tabla.

Si te interesa escuchar los cambios de los checkbox, puedes alcanzar los checkbox en particular, aquí lo hago con [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll), alcazándolos por tipo y por nombre, por si tuvieras otros checkbox que no quieres alcanzar para este propósito.

Luego, para obtener los valores de los `td` de la fila que ha cambiado puedes usar [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) y a partir de ahí, obtener los datos de cada columna.

Otra cosa, **no abuses de los `id`** y **no crees `id` duplicados**. Dado que tus elementos se crean en un bucle, si **realmente** necesitas los `id` para cada elemento debes crear un número incremental y asignarlo al final para garantizar que cada `id` es diferente.

Como podrás ver en la respuesta, puede que no sea necesario que cada `td` tenga un `id`. Si no necesitas diferenciarlos para algo en particular, no tienes por qué ponerles `id` a todos.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo con tres filas que he construido a mano, porque no tengo el contexto PHP, con el que se crea tu tabla.

```js
document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox][name=checkname]").forEach(link => {
  link.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (e.target.checked) {
      var tr = e.target.closest('tr');
      var str = `${tr.cells[1].innerText} ${tr.cells[2].innerText} ${tr.cells[3].innerText} ${tr.cells[4].innerText}`
      console.log(str);
      alert(str);
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <h1> Listado de Usuarios </h1>
  <table id="tabla">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Selecciona</th>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>Nombres</th>
        <th>Apellido Paterno</th>
        <th>Apellido Materno</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <?php foreach ($resultado as $fila){ ?>

      <!--  Se muestra el valor de cada columna en la tabla,  Asigno al check en id y value los valores que deseo obtener en la alerta -->
      <tr>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkname" value="n1" class="classchk"></td>
        <td>
          1
        </td>
        <td>
          Nombre 1
        </td>
        <td>
          AP 1
        </td>
        <td>
          AM 1
        </td>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkname" value="n3" class="classchk"></td>
          <td>
            2
          </td>
          <td>
            Nombre 2
          </td>
          <td>
            AP 2
          </td>
          <td>
            AM 2
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><input type="checkbox" name="checkname" value="n3" class="classchk"></td>
          <td>
            3
          </td>
          <td>
            Nombre 3
          </td>
          <td>
            AP 3
          </td>
          <td>
            AM 3
          </td>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

#### PD

Si quieres recoger todos los `td` sin tener que ponerlos por cada índice puedes hacer esto:

```
if (e.target.checked) {
    var tr = e.target.closest('tr');
    var str="";       
    for (var i = 1; i < tr.cells.length; i++) {
        str+= `${tr.cells[i].innerText}`;  
    }
    console.log(str);
    alert(str);
}
```

El bucle empieza en la posición `1`, para ignorar el checkbox, que estaría en la posición `0` y se asume que todos los demás elementos contienen solamente texto dentro.

Comment: MIL GRACIAS, esto era la que buscaba, ahora solo una cuestión, si fuesen mas columnas, puedo asignar el numero de celda a través de un ciclo, sin necesidad de agregarlos manualmente

Comment: @AlbertoCordova claro, puedes hacer algo así: `var str="";
      for (var i = 1; i < tr.cells.length; i++) {
        str+= ``${tr.cells[i].innerText}``;` En la concatenación de `str` pon solo un backstick al inicio y otro al final, puse dos en el comentario para que se vea bien. Mejor lo pondré en la respuesta.
      }
      console.log(str);` He empezado el bucle en la posición 1 para que salte al checkbox.

Comment: Mil gracias por tan valiosa ayuda y consejos brindados

Comment: @AlbertoCordova  me alegro de haberte ayudado. Si la respuesta dada ha resuelto tu problema puedes marcarla como aceptada, de modo que la pregunta no aparezca como sin resolver. Saludos.